# How do I get the native "look and feel" using WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I've just started developing a WPF application. This is not my first WPF app, but it will be the first that needs some polish. I know quite a bit about the "plumbing" of WPF such as binding, etc., but very little about how to polish it up. I don't need a snazzy UI. I just need something that looks like a native Windows app. For instance, if the app runs on XP, I want it to look like an XP app and pick up the user's UI theme. Same thing on Vista, etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything - WPF does it for you.

EDIT: It does. Run it with Aero/Luna and then Classic.

Comment: My problem ended up being with the Window background.

Comment: I ran into a similar window background color issue. I ended up having to explicitly set it using windows.system.colors.  Maybe someone who knows more has a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to put this into the application's OnLoad event to use the Vista theme, for example:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("PresentationFramework.Aero;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml", UriKind.Relative); 

Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Application.LoadComponent(uri) as ResourceDictionary);
```

or for the Windows XP theme:
themes/Royale.normalcolor.xaml