# Native UI using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm switching from Windows Forms to WPF, but WPF's GUI is really ugly. It looks like Windows 95 or something like that.

Example:

- Left is a new WPF project
- Right is a new Windows Forms project

Both only have a button and textbox added to the project, no other changes.

[image: Comparison]

As you can see, WPF doesn't have the "native Windows GUI". **I know that I can use themes**, but I just want the native Windows GUI. Isn't there any setting to do this without themes? I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380116/how-do-i-get-the-native-look-and-feel-using-wpf) but I didn't change anything in the project except for the button and the textbox and it still doesn't look native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this workaround](http://rudiv.se/Article/code-examples/windows-8-release-preview-button-textbox-style-wpf). there's some button styles there to make the buttons look more similar to the native ones. Other than that, see [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776142/wpf-built-in-theme-for-desktop-apps-on-windows-8-looks-substandard#) the official statement from Microsoft that this difference is actually by design. They made intentional changes to the themes to make them more lightweight by removing gradients and such.

Comment: That just makes no sense. Why would it work in XP, Vista, 7 but not 8? It really looks ugly compared to the rest of Windows. I guess that if I use the theme the native look for XP and Vista will be gone also? Better stay with Windows Forms then. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed - this is nuts. I want to host a WPF usercontrol inside a Visual Studio Package property page (using the ElementHost control) and have the look and feel look just like the standard property pages, but I can't do this - even this work around doesn't reskin controls like the ComboBox. Surely if this is by design, then a fully working stylesheet could be provided for scenarios where seamlessly hosting WPF in Winforms is needed?